# What have I done wrong with these unordered lists?

Tags: html, css, list, css-tables, unordered

I'm trying to get 2 unordered lists working in a div to achieve two different sized columns, but for some reason there is this extra top/bottom padding within the div that I don't want there.

```
#contact-box {
    float: right;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: green;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 0px;
}

        ul#networks {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
            width: ;
            padding: 0px;
        }
            #networks li {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 7px;

            }

        ul#contacts {
            list-style-type: none;
            float: right;
            width: 70%;
            background-color: red;
            padding: 0px;           

        }
            #contacts li {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 7px;
            }
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/XwfLD/
I know it's going to be something simple in the CSS, but if anybody could help it would be appreciated!

Comment: Because you're using ul which has a margin, if you use div and stack them like ul you'll get what you want even you dont put margin:0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these lines:

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwfLD/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your issue is you don't have a width specified for ul#networks.. if you change

```
ul#networks {
list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: ;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

To..

```
ul#networks {
list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 30% ;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

They should move beside each other. From your description I believe that is what you want. Let me know how that works.

Comment: I don't believe that JunM's solution actually achieves what you are trying to accomplish... By default an **unordered list will still take up 100% width of it's container**. This means that you cannot possibly have two ul's beside each other within a div. Taking away the **margin** and **padding** will only make the vertical distance between them smaller. I hope this helps :).